# How to to make columns line up with awk in unix

Tags: unix

I'm trying to make my columns line up in my UNIX code to show a sort of chart, but they just keep going down to a new line and not formatting to a new chart column. I need them to line up and format using AWK. Sort of like this

```
#        Name                        ID #       Reg Method  Level      Cred   Email  

    ---  --------------------------  ---------  ----------  ---------  -----  ------ 
      1  Chapin, Kayla M.            AAAAAAAAA  Web         Undergrad  3.0    XXXXXXX
      2  Ding, Anqi                  AAAAAAAAA  Web         Undergrad  3.0    XXXXXXX 
      3  Fustich, Joshua             AAAAAAAAA  Web         Undergrad  3.0    XXXXXXX
```

[What it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqcK5.png)

Comment: read about `printf` and it's format strings and parameters. For your 2nd column `%-20s` should be a good start. Good luck.

Comment: You might want to use `split -l filename` and `paste`

Answer (score 0):

use `printf` in awk command.

```
awk '{ printf "%3d %26s %9s %10s %9s %5s %20s \n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7 }' file.txt
```

### More info for reference

#### `awk printf` supported datatypes

```
%i or d --Decimal
%o --Octal
%x --hex
%c --ASCII number character
%s --String
%f --floating number
```

#### Padding options

```
-n --Pad n spaces on right hand side of a column.
n --Pad n spaces on left hand side of a column.
.m --Add zeros on left side.
-n.m --Pad n spaces right hand side and add m zeros before that number.
n.m --Pad n spaces left hand side and add m zeros before that.
```